# How do I submit button on other site using chrome extensions & js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to make a bot that goes to web-shop page, selects an item and adds it to a cart. I've successfully got the page, found an item and then faced with question how do I press a button (add to card).

Im my code I try to find this button:

```html
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">
```

Find it with value and press it with js:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("add to basket")[0].click();
```

Also when I try do do it with hands on site I see this request in Inspector http://*url*/shop/304564/add - should I pay attention about this?

I've tried many ways to do it but nothing happens. Am I really wrong and thinking not there? May you recommend other way to "click" that button. thanks for your opinions! =)

HTML on site

```html
<div id="cctrl">
    <form class="add" id="cart-addf" action="/shop/304564/add" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value="27204">
        <fieldset>
            <select name="size" id="size">
                <option value="59099">Medium</option>
                <option value="59100">Large</option>
                <option value="59101">XLarge</option>
            </select>
            <a class="next" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/no940ki56">next tops/sweater &gt;</a>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">
            <a class="button continue" href="/shop">keep shopping</a>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

My JS code

```
function pickItem() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('item_name', function (data) {
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('name-link');

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if((items[i].innerHTML).includes(item_name)){

                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i].href});

                break;
            }
        }

    });
}

function addToBasket() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('submit', function (data) {

        document.getElementsByTagName("add to basket")[0].click();

    });
}

if(url == "*url*") {
    pickCategory();
}

if(url != "*url*"){
    pickItem();

    addToBasket();
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("add to basket")[0].click();` - `add to basket` is not a tag name. ALWAYS check your selectors are finding the elements you think they are.

Comment: @Utkanos so if I correct it with: 

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="add to basket"]');
elements[0].click();

that's gonna work? .click() method is correct?

Comment: @Utkanos thanks very much such a dummmm mistake!!! it works =)